# Sync Tableau Online group membership with Active Directory or Okta

Tags: active-directory, okta, tableau-api

Here is our setup

- Users and groups are setup in `Active Directory`
- Users and groups are pulled into `Okta` from `Active Directory`
- Tableau Online is configured with `SAML` authentication with `Okta`
- Users sign in to Tableau online using `SAML` thru `Okta`

My goal: 
I want to secure data within `Tableau Desktop` using groups. So the way we currently do this is to create a group in `Tableau Online` then manually add users to that group although the group/user association is already done in `AD` and in `Okta`. Is there a way to automatically or with an `API` to sync `Tableau Online` groups with `Active Directory` or `Okta` groups?

Comment: Is the source of truth for your groups AD or Tableau?
Have you seen: https://help.okta.com/en/prev/Content/Topics/Apps/Apps_App_Integration_Wizard.htm

Comment: @BrianDemers, this will not work for us. We need to not just secure the app, we want to secure the data presented in Tableau desktop based on the group. The source of truth is AD

Comment: Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: Nop. Sorry! No solution